# Test storage Permission in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to flutter and want to write test code for permission handling but unable to understand where i am doing wrong anybody has any idea please reply i am using mocktail for mocking
here is my **Homepage** widget

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      PlatformWrapperChecker wrapper;
 HomePage({Key? key, required this.wrapper}) : super(key: key);

   @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
 }

   class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var fileutils = FileUtility();
  List<String> pdfPaths = [];
  List<String> filePath = [];
  PermissionHandlerWrapper handler = PermissionHandlerWrapper();
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
   requestPermissionAndRefresh();
  }

 requestPermissionAndRefresh() async {
   Permission permission = Permission.storage;
   bool isPermission = await handler.requestStoragePermission(permission);
   if (isPermission) {
       setState(() {
          refreshAndListen();
        });
    } else {
       debugPrint('Permission not granted');
   }
  }
```

and my **PermissionHandlerWrapper** Class

```
   import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
   import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

     class PermissionHandlerWrapper {
         Future<bool> requestStoragePermission(Permission permission) async {
       // Check if the permission is already granted
        var status = await permission.status;

if (!status.isGranted) {
  // If the permission is not granted, request it
  status = await permission.request();
  return Future.value(true);
}

// Handle the permission status
if (status.isGranted) {
  // Permission granted
  debugPrint("Storage permission is granted.");
  return Future.value(true);
} else {
  // Permission denied
  debugPrint("Storage permission is denied.");
  return Future.value(false);
}
```

}
}

and test file is this

```
 class MockPermissionHandler extends Mock implements 
 PermissionHandlerWrapper {}

testWidgets("Test permission handling when permission is granted",
    (tester) async {
  Permission permission = Permission.storage; //here static method

  when(() => permissonMock.requestStoragePermission(permission))
      .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(true));

  await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(
    wrapper: platformWrapper,
  )));

  final homePageFinder = find.byType(HomePage);
  final homePageState = tester.state<HomePageState>(homePageFinder);

  // Call the method
  await homePageState.requestPermissionAndRefresh();

  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  verify(() => homePageState.refreshAndListen()).called(1);

  // Ensure no other unexpected interactions occurred
  verifyNoMoreInteractions(homePageState);

  // Wait for async operations to complete
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
});
```